# Passing data from native to react native

Tags: ios, file, react-native, properties

My application has the following steps:

1. Send file with own extension to user's email
2. When file is opened, the app is started (after user has select it)
3. Now I want to use the data from the file.

**But how?**

I added following function to my AppDelegate.m file in Xcode.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  if (url){
    NSString *information = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
    //this is not the way to display this on the screen
    NSLog(@"The file contained: %@",information);
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Is it possible to use this information string in react-native? What do I need to add to use it as 'this.props.information' in my react-native app?